# flashlog viewer

Tags: apache-flex, air, logging, flashlog

I want to build an application using air. The application should load the flashlog file and display the contents after performing some text filtering.
But when i load the application this clears my flashlog.txt though my file mode is READ.

I can understand that running my air application clears the flashlog and prepares it for new logging. Is there a workaround for this.

I dont want to open the flashlog file everytime and check for traces from my web application

Answer (score 0):

You might try http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/wiki/ThunderBoltAS3 or run tail -f on the flash log file.